# ActiveAdmin, CanCan, Rolify - Cannot conditionally disable filters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

So far most of the stuff in this combined setup works well enough. However, when I try to conditionally disable filters, they are simply always enabled. My scenario is (more or less) that I want to give `Restaurant` owners (`AdminUser`s with the role `:restaurateur`) partial access: they can only edit their own Restaurant, and I also want to hide some fields from them, too. This works. But disabling filters doesn't. Let me elaborate:

```
# app/admin/restaurants.rb
batch_action :activate, :if => proc { can? :activate, Restaurant } do |list|
  #...
end
controller do
  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin_user)
  end
end
index do
  ...
  column :city if can? :manage, Restaurant             # This works well.
end
filter :city, :if => proc { can? :manage, Restaurant } # This is always there.
```

The `Ability`:

```
# app/models/ability.rb
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.has_role? :restaurateur
  cannot :manage, Restaurant
```

Here's what I see in the Rails console:

```
 admin = AdminUser.find(1)                           # roles => [:admin]
 restorateur = AdminUser.find(2)                     # roles => [:restaurateur]
 Ability.new(admin).can?(:manage, Restaurant)        # true
 Ability.new(restorateur).can?(:manage, Restaurant)  # false
```

I understand I am not using it the best way possible, like using the `:manage` verb which in the common case is not intended to provide partial access. But it works, except for disabling the filters.

AND

Is there anything special I should be doing so these would indeed work?

Rolify is at `3.2.0`. CanCan is at `1.6.8`. ActiveAdmin is at this GIT revision: `b0dd8fdcfbd68984a8c2ec7f2279a121eeb66c3d`. If I update it to the latest GIT revision  (or the official 0.5.0 release), `batch_action`s always get disabled! *(And thus they disable the `selectable_column` as well.)*

**On to my questions:**

Is there any reliable way to test Abilities inside ActiveAdmin's file? Maybe the way the Abilities are instantiated feeds them the wrong user (I mean before checking the filter `:if` Proc)? I am little at loss on how does the `can?` helper gets an Ability instantiated in this case.

AND

What's the recommended way of conditionally disabling filters, if my way is incorrect?

AND

Anyone having an idea of why ActiveAdmin's latest version seems to outright **ignore** batch actions? Maybe I should put the `controller do` block *before* the `batch_action` blocks?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am guessing I have to take it to ActiveAdmin's issue list then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution in this [issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/938).

After applying this monkeypatch:

```
# config/initializers/activeadmin_filter_conditions.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  module Filters
    class FormBuilder < ::ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder
      def filter(method, options = {})
        return "" if method.blank?
        if options[:if].is_a?(Proc)
          return "" if !template.instance_eval(&options[:if])
        end
        options[:as] ||= default_input_type(method)
        return "" unless options[:as]
        content = input(method, options)
        form_buffers.last << content.html_safe if content
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you should be able to use conditions in filters using the way you mentioned:

```
filter :city, :if => proc { can? :manage, Restaurant }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna check it out and accept your answer if it works. =)

Comment: It works very well for me, just don't forget to restart your rails server after adding monkeypatch. =)

Comment: I totally forgot to accept this answer. My bad. Did it now.